# Java: parse xml file using SAX

Tags: java, xml, parsing, soap, sax

I have [this xml data](http://smdp.mihaivlasceanu.eu/CON729.xml) to parse using SAX. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the data from it. The most important thing to get from it is the encoded data (fileContent) which I believe is base64. What I need to do with that is to make an Excel .xls file from it. I have tried some things, but I can only get some field/node (e.g. refNumber, userEmail, etc.) names, but not their actual value. I have placed some code snippets below. Could anyone please help me?

Thanks!

```
class SomeClass {
...
private String currentElement;
...
public Result parseSerializedData(String serializedData) throws SAXException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException
    {
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("Serialized: " + serializedData);
        Source src = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource(new StringReader(serializedData)));
        Result res = new StreamResult(System.out);
        System.out.println("Res 1:" + res);

        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(src, res);
        System.out.println("transform 1:" + res);

        try {
         SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
         SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
         saxParser.parse(serializedData, new MyHandler());
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

        System.out.println("The current element is: " + currentElement);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        return res;
    }

    /*
    * Inner class for the Callback Handlers.
    */
   class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
      // Callback to handle element start tag
      @Override
      public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
          System.out.println("qName: " + qName);
         currentElement = qName;
      }

      // Callback to handle element end tag
      @Override
      public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
         currentElement = "";
      }

      // Callback to handle the character text data inside an element
      @Override
      public void characters(char[] chars, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
          try {
            byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(String.valueOf(chars));
              System.out.println("The current element2 is: " + currentElement);
              if (currentElement.equals("fileContent")) {
                System.out.println("\tfileContent:\t" + new String(decodedBytes, start, length));
             }
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
          }

      }
   }
}
```

`serializedData` is the contents of that xml file

Comment: "I can only get some filed names." Can you elaborate this? Are you getting partial file content value?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the `characters` method is where the values are read. In your case you were printing only for one tag. `if (currentElement.equals("fileContent"))`. Follow the below program. This displays all values of all tags. Another thing to notice is the `characters` method reads a chuck of max 2048 bytes (if i remember correctly), so the best approach is to use append later process the value in `endElement()` method as shown in the example. Please not I'm using [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) for Base64 decoding. You could use your own decoder.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SaxSample {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                StringBuilder value;

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {
                    value = new StringBuilder();
                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName) throws SAXException {
                    if ("fileContent".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
                        String decodedValue = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(value.toString()));
                        System.out.println(qName + " = " + decodedValue);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(qName + " = " + value);
                    }
                    value = new StringBuilder();
                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                        throws SAXException {
                    value.append(new String(ch, start, length));
                }

            };

            saxParser.parse(new File("data.xml"), handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code seems to work and it does what it should. However, I did not know until now that the base64 encoding is the actual excel file. I need to save that data into a physical .xls file that can be opened with Microsoft Excel. I asked a question here, if you could help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022955/java-save-excel-file-from-existing-base64-encoding Thanks!