# Save Excel file from existing base64 encoding

Tags: java, excel, sax

I have an existing base64 encoding of an Excel file [from this xml file](http://smdp.mihaivlasceanu.eu/CON729.xml) and I want to save that data (fileContent) to a physical excel file, but I am stuck doing it. I've seen some tutorials on how to encode it, but I couldn't get it to work on saving that data into a file that can be opened with Microsoft Excel. The solutions I tried prints all the data as excel entries (see attached image). I have [asked a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018587/java-parse-xml-file-using-sax/25021325), but I did not know that the encoded data is an actual .xls file.

Here's the code that does that:

```
package parsing;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SaxSample {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                StringBuilder value;

                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {
                    value = new StringBuilder();
                }

                @Override
                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName) throws SAXException {
                    if ("fileContent".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
                        FileInputStream fis = null;
                        try {
                            String decodedValue = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(value.toString()));
                            value.append(decodedValue);
                            // The name of the file to create.
                            String fileName = "temp.xls";
                            File file = new File(fileName);
                            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                            BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                            inputStream.read(fileBytes);
                            inputStream.close();
                            System.out.println(qName + " = " + decodedValue);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(SaxSample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(SaxSample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                fis.close();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(SaxSample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(qName + " = " + value);
                    }
                    value = new StringBuilder();
                }

                @Override
                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                        throws SAXException {
                    value.append(new String(ch, start, length));
                }

            };

            saxParser.parse(new File("src/parsing/CON729.xml"), handler);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your method `endElement(...)` but if you want to get a readable excel file, just transform the encoded base64 to a byte array (NOT TO ANOTHER STRING) i. e. change your `endElement(...)` like this:

```
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                       String qName) throws SAXException {
    if ("fileContent".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("temp.xls"), DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(value.toString()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SaxSample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        // I'm still not sure why you're printing this ... debugging?
        System.out.println(qName + " = " + value);
    }
}
```

The only thing you need to do is:

- get the content of the element `fileContent` (you're already doing that)
- decode this content into a byte array
- save this byte array in a file (no need to do further conversions)

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

RunTimePersmision is Required

```
public static void storetoExcelandOpen(Context context, String base,String name) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File myDir = new File(root + "/WorkBox");
    if (!myDir.exists()) {
        myDir.mkdirs();
    }

    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);

    String fname = name+n+".xlsx";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] excelAsBytes = Base64.decode(base, 0);
        out.write(excelAsBytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WorkBox");
    File imgFile = new File(dir, fname);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } else {
        uri = Uri.parse("file://" + imgFile); // My work-around for new SDKs, causes ActivityNotFoundException in API 10.
    }

    sendIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(sendIntent);

}
```